# Dynamics CRM v4 monitor mailbox for a queue

Tags: queue, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, router

Hi I want to set up Microsoft Dynamics CRM to monitor a single mailbox using pop3 and then have any mails in that mailbox added as email activities to a queue in CRM.

I have set up the pop3 mail box and I know that it works.

I have set up the email router with an incoming profile for the mailbox.

I have a queue called "inbound" in CRM and I can see it in the Users and Queues section of the Email router interface. Its inbound profile is set to the correct profile.

I have published the changes but the emails do not make it into the queue.

CRM is definitely accessing the mailbox and downloading the emails... so where are they going?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things to check.  When you open the queue in CRM make sure that the "Incoming Email" option is set to "All e-mail messages", also make sure that the "E-mail access type - incoming:" and "E-mail access type - outgoing" are both set to "Forward Mailbox".  Now, go back to your email router configuration screen and make sure you've set up the right forwarding rule with the queue's email.

Do a test and see if both inbound and outbound succeed.